# Export PSCustomObject containing HashTable to CSV

Tags: powershell, export-to-csv, pscustomobject

My Object is Structured like this

```
$ToExport = [pscustomobject]@{
           "samAccountName" = ''
           "forwarded" = @{
                "ForwardTo" = ""
                "RedirectTo" = ""
           }
}
```

When i now try to export it into a CSV i achieved two things, first i recieve the samaccountname and under forwarded only System.Collections.Hashtable appears. The second possibility including

```
Select * -ExpandProperty "forwarded"
```

now doesnt display the samAccountname in the export anymore, only the name of the forwarded object and the two objects ForwardedTo and RedirectedTO

Incase this is in any way important: The purpose of the script is to pass through all mailboxes and display all forwarding rules, thats also the reason why forwarding is a hashtable that can contain multiple entries.

Is there a possibility to get this object in a structured way into a csv or do i have to use Json or any other type of data structure?

In advance thanks for any help.

Comment: You could convert the hashtable to json and store that in the CSV

Comment: So basically $ToExport.forwarded | ConverttT-Json | Export-CSV .... ? Or as a step between in a variable $localforwarded so i can then store $ToExport.samAccountname and $localforwarded in the same line in csv.

Comment: CSV is not well suited for nested structures. If you are determined to store the data I would recommend choosing a different data structure like JSON or XML. Usually in my experience when somebody wants to export nested objects or arrays they intend to import the data to something later, and are just using CSV due to familiarity. If you don't need to manipulate it in Excel or something give JSON or XML a shot, and you'll probably be pleased with the results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, one compromise is to embed JSON in the CSV:

```
$flatExport = $ToExport |Select SAMAccountName,@{Name='forwarded';Expression={$_.forwarded |ConvertTo-Json -Compress}}
$flatExport |Export-Csv -Path path\to\export.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

This will work well if the eventual consumer of the CSV is also a PowerShell script or otherwise recognizes `""` as a valid escape sequence for `"`.

Otherwise you'll have to pick a serialization format better fit for hierarchical data, like exporting the whole thing to JSON for example:

```
$ToExport |ConvertTo-Json -Compress |Set-Content export.json
```